# The member imageFile of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile cannot be used as a parameter value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Web API project in asp.net core 6.0 using VS2022. I got exception using IFormFile member can't be used as parameter. Following are details.

**Model**

```
 public class InstituteInfo
    {
        public int? ID { get; set; } = 1;
        public string Institute_Name { get; set; } = "";
        public string Office_No { get; set; } = "";
        public string Cell_No { get; set; } = "";
        public string email { get; set; } = "";
        public string Institute_address { get; set; } = "";
        public string monogramPath { get; set; } = "";
        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile? imageFile { get; set; }
    }
```

**DB Access Class using Dapper ORM framework**

```
public class SQLDataAccess : ISQLDataAccess
 {
     private readonly IConfiguration _config;

     public SQLDataAccess(IConfiguration config)
     {
         _config = config;
     }
    
     public int SaveInstitute(InstituteInfo info, string connectionID = "Default")
     {
         var values = new InstituteInfo { Institute_Name=info.Institute_Name, Office_No = info.Office_No, Cell_No = info.Cell_No, email = info.email, Institute_address = info.Institute_address,monogramPath=info.monogramPath};
         using IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString(connectionID));
         var x = connection.Execute("sp_SaveNewInstitute", values, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
         return x;
     }

 }
```

**Controller and Action Method**

```
public class InstituteAPIController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ISQLDataAccess _sqlDataAccess;
    private readonly IFileService _fileService;
    public InstituteAPIController(ISQLDataAccess sQLDataAccess, IFileService fileService)
    {
        _sqlDataAccess = sQLDataAccess;
        _fileService = fileService;
    }

    // POST api/<InstituteAPIController>
    [Route("Institute/AddNew")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromForm] InstituteInfo Newinfo)
    {
        try
        {
             var fileResult = _fileService.SaveImage(Newinfo.imageFile, 2);
             if(fileResult != null) 
             {
                if (fileResult.Item1 == 1)
                {
                    Newinfo.monogramPath = fileResult.Item2;
                }
                var result = _sqlDataAccess.SaveInstitute(Newinfo);
               Ok( result);
             }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = ex.Message;

        }
    }

    // PUT api/<InstituteAPIController>/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/<InstituteAPIController>/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

When I run and input values using Swagger, i get exception on following line of code:

```
var result = _sqlDataAccess.SaveInstitute(Newinfo);
```

> The member **imageFile **of type **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile** cannot be used as a parameter value. **System.NotSupportedException**

I have googled but nothing is fruitful. Kindly check where i am doing mistake and how to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try with anonymous type here

modify

```
var values = new InstituteInfo { Institute_Name=info.Institute_Name, Office_No = info.Office_No, Cell_No = info.Cell_No, email = info.email, Institute_address = info.Institute_address,monogramPath=info.monogramPath};
```

to

```
var values = new { Institute_Name=info.Institute_Name, Office_No = info.Office_No, Cell_No = info.Cell_No, email = info.email, Institute_address = info.Institute_address,monogramPath=info.monogramPath};
```

Comment: That works great.